# How to display time reminder from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table that displays data from the database. For example, something like this:

```
<table>                       
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Start Time</th>
    <th>End Time</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>French</td>
    <td>21 December 1992</td>
    <td>23:00</td>
    <td>05:00</td> 
  </tr>
```

I want to know how to display how many hours I have left until it starts. Ex: French starts in 2 hours. I know I'll need the current time but I'm not really sure how to go about it.

**EDIT**

If there's more than one data in the database, I also want to know how to display the earliest one.

```
$sql = DB::getInstance()->get('sessions', array('MONTH(date)','=' ,$userSelection));
//mysql_db_query('nio', "SELECT DATE");
echo "<table class='table table-hover'style='color: orange' > "
    ."<thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Start Time</th>
          <th>End Time</th>
        </tr> 
      </thead>
    <tbody>";

if(!$sql->count()){
  echo 'No data';
}else {
  foreach ($sql->results() as $sql){ 
    echo "<tr style='background-color: black'>";
    echo "<td><a href = session-options.php>" .  $sql->title . "</a></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $sql->date . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $sql->start_time . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $sql->end_time . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  ?>
                <?php }}echo"   </tbody>";
 echo" </table>";
}     

?>
```

It displays as a table on the webpage. And this is how it's added to the db:

```
try {
  $user->createSession(array(
           'title' => Input::get('title'),
           'date' => Input::get('date'),
           'start_time' => Input::get('timepicker1'),
           'end_time' => Input::get('timepicker2'),
           'passcode' => (Input::get('passcode')),
           'username' => $user->data()->username,
           'module' => $module
));
```

### ------

```
<div class="input-group date" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" id="date" placeholder="Choose Date:">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i>
  </span>
</div> <br>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-5"><div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker top-margin"> Start Time:
      <input id="timepicker1" type="text"  name="timepicker1">
      <span class="add-on"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-5">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker top-margin"> End Time:
      <input id="timepicker2" type="text"  name="timepicker2">
      <span class="add-on">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below code. You can use '$sql->start_time' in place of '$start_time' and '$sql->date' in place of '$start_date'. check for your your [default_timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");

$start_date = '2015-03-02';
$start_time = '04:15:58';
$current_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());


$start_datetime = new DateTime($start_date.' '.$start_time);
$end_datetime = new DateTime($current_datetime);

$since_start = $start_datetime->diff($end_datetime);

echo ($since_start->days * 24)+$since_start->h.' hours / ';
echo $since_start->i.' minutes / ';
echo $since_start->s.' seconds remaining';
```

The above code gives output as:

> 2 hours / 22 minutes / 30 seconds remaining

You can edit as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. Although, I seriously don't know why I got this many downvotes. I don't understand. Thanks for the help.